# Adding NULLs to a UNPIVOTed query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I go about including NULL values in my below `SELECT` query? Researching this, I found that I can use either a `CROSS JOIN` AND `CASE` or use a `CROSS APPLY` instead of `UNPIVOT` which will not bring in NULLs.

I don't have experience with either one. What do you all prefer? Can someone provide an example? My query below:

```
SELECT     PARTNO, DATETIME, PLANT_NAME, SAP_PLANT_CODE, SHIFT, EVENT, BASE_CODE, SIGNON_ID, PROPERTY, LINE_NUMBER, SSIZE, NCU, SUMDEFECTS, PARTNOAUX, PROCESSAUX, DATETIMEAUX, UDL7, MACHINE, 
                         DMS_SAP_SPEC_NO, UDL10, UDL11, CAVITY, ROW_NUMBER, DEPARTMENT, UDL15, UDL16, UDL17, INSPECTOR, SAP_MATERIAL_NUMBER, UDL20, POSITION, LOCATION, UDL23, HOT_COLD, UDL25, UDL26, SPEC_TYPE, 
                         PROPERTY_TREE, UDL29, DEFECT_TYPE, UDL31, UDL32, MOLDBASE, UDL34, UDL35, UDL36, UDL37, CUSTOMER, UDL39, SAMPLEDATE, UDL41, UDL42, UDL43, UDL44, UDL45, UDL46, SUB_INSPECTION, PC_COLLECT_2, 
                         --DefectName, DefectValue, 
                         CountName, CountValue
FROM            (SELECT        OC_DDATA_PC.PARTNO, OC_DDATA_PC.DATETIME, stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS.PLANT_NAME, OC_DDATA_PC.UDL1 AS SAP_PLANT_CODE, OC_DDATA_PC.UDL2 AS SHIFT, OC_DDATA_PC.EVENT, 
                         OC_DDATA_PC.UDL3 AS BASE_CODE, OC_DDATA_PC.UDL4 AS SIGNON_ID, OC_DDATA_PC.UDL5 AS PROPERTY, OC_DDATA_PC.UDL6 AS LINE_NUMBER, OC_DDATA_PC.SSIZE, OC_DDATA_PC.NCU, 
                         OC_DDATA_PC.SUMDEFECTS, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.PARTNOAUX, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.PROCESSAUX, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.DATETIMEAUX, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL7, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL8 AS MACHINE, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL9 AS DMS_SAP_SPEC_NO, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL10, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL11, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL12 AS CAVITY, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL13 AS ROW_NUMBER, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL14 AS DEPARTMENT, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL15, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL16, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL17, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL18 AS INSPECTOR, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL19 AS SAP_MATERIAL_NUMBER, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL20, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL21 AS POSITION, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL22 AS LOCATION, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL23, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL24 AS HOT_COLD, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL25, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL26, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL27 AS SPEC_TYPE, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL28 AS PROPERTY_TREE, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL29, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL30 AS DEFECT_TYPE, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL31, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL32, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL33 AS MOLDBASE, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL34, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL35, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL36, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL37, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL38 AS CUSTOMER, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL39, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL40 AS SAMPLEDATE, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL41, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL42, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL43, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL44, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL45, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL46, OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL47 AS SUB_INSPECTION, 
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL48 AS PC_COLLECT_2, OC_DMDL_PC.DESCRIPT AS DefectName1, OC_DMDL_PC_1.DESCRIPT AS DefectName2, OC_DMDL_PC_2.DESCRIPT AS DefectName3, 
                         OC_DMDL_PC_3.DESCRIPT AS DefectName4, OC_DMDL_PC_4.DESCRIPT AS DefectName5, OC_DMDL_PC_5.DESCRIPT AS DefectName6, OC_DMDL_PC_6.DESCRIPT AS DefectName7, 
                         OC_DMDL_PC_7.DESCRIPT AS DefectName8, OC_DMDL_PC_8.DESCRIPT AS DefectName9, OC_DMDL_PC_9.DESCRIPT AS DefectName10, OC_DMDL_PC_10.DESCRIPT AS DefectName11, 
                         OC_DMDL_PC_11.DESCRIPT AS DefectName12, OC_DMDL_PC_12.DESCRIPT AS DefectName13, OC_DMDL_PC_13.DESCRIPT AS DefectName14, OC_DMDL_PC_14.DESCRIPT AS DefectName15, 
                         OC_DMDL_PC_15.DESCRIPT AS DefectName16, OC_DMDL_PC_16.DESCRIPT AS DefectName17, OC_DMDL_PC_17.DESCRIPT AS DefectName18, OC_DMDL_PC_18.DESCRIPT AS DefectName19, 
                         OC_DMDL_PC_19.DESCRIPT AS DefectName20, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT1, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT2, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT3, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT4, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT5, 
                         OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT6, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT7, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT8, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT9, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT10, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT11, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT12, 
                         OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT13, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT14, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT15, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT16, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT17, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT18, OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT19, 
                         OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT20
FROM            OC_DDATA_PC INNER JOIN
                         OC_DDAT_AUX_PC ON OC_DDATA_PC.PARTNO = OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.PARTNOAUX AND OC_DDATA_PC.DATETIME = OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.DATETIMEAUX INNER JOIN
                         stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS ON OC_DDATA_PC.UDL1 = stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS.PLANT_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID1 = OC_DMDL_PC.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_1 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID2 = OC_DMDL_PC_1.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_2 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID3 = OC_DMDL_PC_2.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_3 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID4 = OC_DMDL_PC_3.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_4 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID5 = OC_DMDL_PC_4.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_5 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID6 = OC_DMDL_PC_5.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_6 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID7 = OC_DMDL_PC_6.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_7 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID8 = OC_DMDL_PC_7.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_8 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID9 = OC_DMDL_PC_8.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_9 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID10 = OC_DMDL_PC_9.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_10 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID11 = OC_DMDL_PC_10.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_11 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID12 = OC_DMDL_PC_11.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_12 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID13 = OC_DMDL_PC_12.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_13 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID14 = OC_DMDL_PC_13.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_14 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID15 = OC_DMDL_PC_14.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_15 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID16 = OC_DMDL_PC_15.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_16 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID17 = OC_DMDL_PC_16.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_17 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID18 = OC_DMDL_PC_17.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_18 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID19 = OC_DMDL_PC_18.DEFECTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OC_DMDL_PC AS OC_DMDL_PC_19 ON OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID20 = OC_DMDL_PC_19.DEFECTID) 
AS SourceData
UNPIVOT
(
    DefectValue FOR DefectName IN
    (
        DefectName1, DefectName2, DefectName3, DefectName4, DefectName5,
        DefectName6, DefectName7, DefectName8, DefectName9, DefectName10,
        DefectName11, DefectName12, DefectName13, DefectName14, DefectName15,
        DefectName16, DefectName17, DefectName18, DefectName19, DefectName20
    )
) AS UnpivotedData
UNPIVOT
(
    CountValue FOR CountName IN
    (
        DEFECTCNT1, DEFECTCNT2, DEFECTCNT3, DEFECTCNT4, DEFECTCNT5,
        DEFECTCNT6, DEFECTCNT7, DEFECTCNT8, DEFECTCNT9, DEFECTCNT10,
        DEFECTCNT11, DEFECTCNT12, DEFECTCNT13, DEFECTCNT14, DEFECTCNT15,
        DEFECTCNT16, DEFECTCNT17, DEFECTCNT18, DEFECTCNT19, DEFECTCNT20
    )
) AS UnpivotedCounts
```

Here's the table data...

```
PARTNO,DATETIME,CAVITY,SSIZE,DEFECTID1,DEFECTID2,DEFECTID3,DEFECTCNT1,DEFECTCNT2,DEFECTCNT3
10B20   2022011111314430        12  91  0   0   1   0   0
10B20   2022011209511423        10  91  0   0   1   0   0
10B20   2022011315280083        10  97  0   0   1   0   0
10B20   2022011411403882        10  81  91  0   1   1   0
10B20   2022011823363688        10  91  0   0   1   0   0
```

And here is the defect values

```
DEFECTID    DESCRIPT
81  MOLD BUILD-UP
91  PITTED SURFACE
97  RIDER
```

Comment: `UNPIVOT` is explicitly [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) to remove `NULL`s. YOu are likely better off with a `VALUES` table construct. They don't have the "feature" and they are (often) far less restrictive.

Comment: We, however, can't run your SQL; we have no definitions or data. I would suggest that you give us more of an [mre], as we don't need *all* of those columns to demonstrate a solution.

Comment: Your data structure seems to suffer from a lack of normalization. When you start adding columns with numbers at the end it indicates you have violated 1NF with what is called repeating groups. It is a very brittle structure and forces silly things like joining the same table over and over and over like your example posted here.

Comment: Thinking about it, wouldn't it make more sense to unpivot *before* you `JOIN`? Then you don't need **twenty** joins to the same table, but *one*.

Comment: *Side note, if you **are** going to number your tables/aliases, then do it consistently, don't start with no suffix, and then have the second instance of the same tables as `_1`. YOu end up joining `2` to `1`, `3` to `2`,... and `20` to `19`. It's* confusing.

Comment: I agree that the data is not normalized at all. However, I can't change the data structure as the program my company purchased is from a third party and, unforunately, I cannot change it.

Comment: The whole code looks defective to me, perhaps you should just start over, you can create a view that unpivots OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTIDXXX columns and it should be much easier to do the rest then

Comment: Alises should be short, 1-4 chars ideally to make the query clearer. And as already said we don't need your production code, just a minimal example which demonstrates the issue

Comment: Let me get a example up.

Comment: @ThomA I will investigate the VALUES table you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #OC_DDATA_PC
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'10B20', 2022011111314430, '', 12, 91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011209511423, '', 10, 91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011315280083, '', 10, 97, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011411403882, '', 10, 81, 91, 0, 1, 1, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011823363688, '', 10, 91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
) t (PARTNO,DATETIME,CAVITY,SSIZE,DEFECTID1,DEFECTID2,DEFECTID3,DEFECTCNT1,DEFECTCNT2,DEFECTCNT3)


SELECT  *
INTO #OC_DMDL_PC
FROM    (
    VALUES  
        (81, N'MOLD BUILD-UP')
    ,   (91, N'PITTED SURFACE')
    ,   (97, N'RIDER')
) t (DEFECTID,DESCRIPT)

SELECT  d.PARTNO, d.DATETIME, CAVITY, SSIZE, def.*, defDesc.*
FROM    #OC_DDATA_PC d
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES  (DEFECTID1, DEFECTCNT1, 1)
    ,   (DEFECTID2, DEFECTCNT2, 2)
    ,   (DEFECTID3, DEFECTCNT3, 3)
    ) def (defId, defCount, def#)
LEFT JOIN #OC_DMDL_PC defDesc
    ON  defDesc.DEFECTID = def.defId
```

Explanation:

```sql
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES  (DEFECTID1, DEFECTCNT1, 1)
    ,   (DEFECTID2, DEFECTCNT2, 2)
    ,   (DEFECTID3, DEFECTCNT3, 3)
    -- Add rest of columns
    ) def (defId, defCount, def#)
```

this part does the UNPIVOTing by converting a single row into a derived table of multiple rows and columns which simplifies your query a lot since the rest is just a single LEFT JOIN.

It also doesn't skip NULLs and you have full control over the columns you want to create which is nice.

Output:

| PARTNO | DATETIME | CAVITY | SSIZE | defId | defCount | def# | DEFECTID | DESCRIPT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10B20 | 2022011111314430 |  | 12 | 91 | 1 | 1 | 91 | PITTED SURFACE |
| 10B20 | 2022011111314430 |  | 12 | 0 | 0 | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011111314430 |  | 12 | 0 | 0 | 3 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011209511423 |  | 10 | 91 | 1 | 1 | 91 | PITTED SURFACE |
| 10B20 | 2022011209511423 |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011209511423 |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 3 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011315280083 |  | 10 | 97 | 1 | 1 | 97 | RIDER |
| 10B20 | 2022011315280083 |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011315280083 |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 3 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011411403882 |  | 10 | 81 | 1 | 1 | 81 | MOLD BUILD-UP |
| 10B20 | 2022011411403882 |  | 10 | 91 | 1 | 2 | 91 | PITTED SURFACE |
| 10B20 | 2022011411403882 |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 3 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011823363688 |  | 10 | 91 | 1 | 1 | 91 | PITTED SURFACE |
| 10B20 | 2022011823363688 |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 10B20 | 2022011823363688 |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 3 | NULL | NULL |