# GROUP BY question with zero and non-zero data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am expanding on the post that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142013/adding-nulls-to-a-unpivoted-query).

In the previous post, I stated that I have a table with 20 DEFECTID fields along with 20 DEFECTCNT fields that come from a third-party company that my company purchased. With help from users, I used this query to get the result set that I want.

```
WITH Unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT
        OC_DDATA_PC.PARTNO,
        CAST(OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL40 AS datetime) AS SAMPLEDATE,
        stagingPLM.DBO.PLANTS.PLANT_NAME,
        OC_DDATA_PC.UDL2 as SHIFT,
        OC_DDATA_PC.UDL4 as SIGNON_ID,
        OC_DDATA_PC.UDL6 as LINE_NUMBER,
        OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL12 as CAVITY,
        OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL27 as SPEC_TYPE,
        OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL28 as PROPERTY_TREE,
        OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL30 as DEFECT_TYPE,
        OC_DDATA_PC.SSIZE,
        ColName,
        ColID,
        ColValue
    FROM            
        OC_DDATA_PC 
    INNER JOIN
        OC_DDAT_AUX_PC ON OC_DDATA_PC.PARTNO = OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.PARTNOAUX AND OC_DDATA_PC.DATETIME = OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.DATETIMEAUX 
    INNER JOIN
        stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS ON OC_DDATA_PC.UDL1 = stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS.PLANT_CODE
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
        ('DEFECTID1',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID1,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT1),
        ('DEFECTID2',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID2,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT2),
        ('DEFECTID3',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID3,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT3),
        ('DEFECTID4',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID4,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT4),
        ('DEFECTID5',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID5,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT5),
        ('DEFECTID6',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID6,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT6),
        ('DEFECTID7',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID7,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT7),
        ('DEFECTID8',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID8,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT8),
        ('DEFECTID9',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID9,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT9),
        ('DEFECTID10',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID10,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT10),
        ('DEFECTID11',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID11,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT11),
        ('DEFECTID12',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID12,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT12),
        ('DEFECTID13',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID13,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT13),
        ('DEFECTID14',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID14,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT14),
        ('DEFECTID15',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID15,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT15),
        ('DEFECTID16',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID16,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT16),
        ('DEFECTID17',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID17,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT17),
        ('DEFECTID18',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID18,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT18),
        ('DEFECTID19',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID19,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT19),
        ('DEFECTID20',OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTID20,OC_DDATA_PC.DEFECTCNT20)

    ) AS Unpvt(ColName, ColID, ColValue)

    -- Currently set up for only for Pulp Plates or Pulp Bowls.
    -- Change the Property Tree (or even a different field) to add/remove records.
    WHERE
        OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.UDL28 LIKE 'PULP %'
)
SELECT *
FROM Unpivoted
```

Now, I need to take it one step farther. I need to `GROUP BY` the `SAMPLEDATE, PARTNO, LINE_NUMBER, CAVITY,` and the `SIGNON_ID`. The second to last column is the DEFECTID that I can do a JOIN on to get the description value. A zero (0) represents that there is no defect.

Every query that I can think of continues to return twenty rows. The above query returns this which is what (I think) I want:

| PARTNO | SAMPLEDATE | PLANT_NAME | SHIFT | SIGNON_ID | LINE_NUMBER | CAVITY | SPEC_TYPE | PROPERTY_TREE | DEFECT_TYPE | SSIZE | DEFECTNAME | DERFECTID | DEFECTCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID1 | 1683 | 10 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID1 | 1683 | 15 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID2 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID2 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID3 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID3 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID4 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID4 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID5 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID5 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID6 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID6 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID7 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID7 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID8 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID8 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID9 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID9 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID10 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID10 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID11 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID11 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID12 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID12 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID13 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID13 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID14 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID14 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID15 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID15 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID16 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID16 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID17 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID17 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID18 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID18 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID19 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID19 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-14 12:23:21.790 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 10 | DEFECTID20 | 0 | 0 |
| 12FBRB | 2024-02-13 16:08:40.280 | Mason Fiber | 3 | D925512 | FORMER 1 |  | BOWLS | PULP BOWLS | CONSTRUCTION | 15 | DEFECTID20 | 0 | 0 |

The result I am looking for would be this (example):

| PARTNO | SAMPLEDATE | PLANT_NAME | SHIFT | SIGNON_ID | LINE_NUMBER | CAVITY | SPEC_TYPE | PROPERTY_TREE | DEFECT_TYPE | SSIZE | DEFECTNAME | DERFECTID | DEFECTCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9FBRP1 | 12/19/2023 09:36:45.51 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D928099 | FORMER 3 |  | PLATES | PULP PLATES | WATER RESISTANCE | 24 | DEFECTID1 | 1681 | 1 |
| 9FBRP1 | 12/19/2023 09:40:38.66 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D928099 | FORMER 4 |  | PLATES | PULP PLATES | GREASE RESISTANCE | 24 | DEFECTID1 | 0 | 0 |
| 9FBRP1 | 12/19/2023 09:47:49.57 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D928099 | FORMER 3 |  | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 24 | DEFECTID1 | 0 | 0 |
| 9FBRP1 | 02/21/2024 08:27:45.68 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 2 | 15 | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 2 | DEFECTID1 | 0 | 0 |
| 9FBRP1 | 02/21/2024 08:27:45.68 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 2 | 25 | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 1 | DEFECTID1 | 1102 | 1 |
| 9FBRP1 | 02/21/2024 08:27:45.68 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 2 | 25 | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 1 | DEFECTID2 | 1683 | 1 |
| 9FBRP1 | 02/21/2024 08:27:45.68 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 2 | 25 | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 1 | DEFECTID3 | 1096 | 1 |
| 9FBRP1 | 02/21/2024 08:27:45.68 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 2 | 25 | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 1 | DEFECTID4 | 1319 | 1 |
| 9FBRP1 | 02/21/2024 08:27:45.68 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 2 | 26 | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 2 | DEFECTID1 | 0 | 0 |
| 9FBRP1 | 02/21/2024 08:27:45.68 | Mason Fiber | 2 | D925512 | FORMER 2 | 28 | PLATES | PULP PLATES | CONSTRUCTION | 2 | DEFECTID1 | 0 | 0 |

This is the output that I am looking for. I still need to report on if no defects were found out of the twenty fields available and their corresponding defect counts.

I am getting pretty defeated here. Is what I am asking for possible?

I know that the tables are not optimized but I cannot change them. I apologize for posting twice on the same subject but I need to come through.

Comment: Sample data? Table structure? This is just a wall of text here with no real context. If this was a consulting gig I would be thrilled to bill you for the time it takes me to setup the problem based on your vague description. But as forum user there is no chance I am going to spend an hour or two of my time creating an environment to work on your problem. Help others to help you by providing the legwork and make it easy for people to help.

Comment: How can I add sample data when there are close to 30 fields?

Comment: Do you really need 30 _columns_ to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I would do it with either a insert statement or create a sql fiddle and post that link. Otherwise you are asking for the people who to do it for you.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, for the base table that comes from the third party which I cannot modify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest to solve it based by previous question is adding a ROW_NUMBER column and then filter by it:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #OC_DDATA_PC
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'10B20', 2022011111314430, '', 12, 91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011209511423, '', 10, 91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011315280083, '', 10, 97, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011411403882, '', 10, 81, 91, 0, 1, 1, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011823363688, '', 10, 91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ,   (N'10B20', 2022011823363689, '', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
) t (PARTNO,DATETIME,CAVITY,SSIZE,DEFECTID1,DEFECTID2,DEFECTID3,DEFECTCNT1,DEFECTCNT2,DEFECTCNT3)


SELECT  *
INTO #OC_DMDL_PC
FROM    (
    VALUES  
        (81, N'MOLD BUILD-UP')
    ,   (91, N'PITTED SURFACE')
    ,   (97, N'RIDER')
) t (DEFECTID,DESCRIPT)

select *
from (
    SELECT  d.PARTNO, d.DATETIME, CAVITY, SSIZE, def.*, defDesc.*
    -- New!
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.PARTNO, d.DATETIME, d.CAVITY, SSIZE ORDER BY -defId) AS defectRank
    FROM    #OC_DDATA_PC d
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES  (DEFECTID1, DEFECTCNT1, 1)
        ,   (DEFECTID2, DEFECTCNT2, 2)
        ,   (DEFECTID3, DEFECTCNT3, 3)
        ) def (defId, defCount, def#)
    LEFT JOIN #OC_DMDL_PC defDesc
        ON  defDesc.DEFECTID = def.defId
      ) x
WHERE defId > 0 OR (defectRank = 1 AND defId = 0) -- NEW
```

Explanation:

Since you want to get all defective rows we add WHERE defId > 0 to the selection.

To handle displaying *one* non-defective row, i add a ROW_NUMBER counter that basically prioritizes defective rows first. So, if first row is non-defective, it means all the other rows are non-defective either, so then we only fetch defectRank = 1.

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.PARTNO, d.DATETIME, d.CAVITY, SSIZE ORDER BY -defId) AS defectRank` - partition by part is the grouping you're looking for, -defID will sort defective rows first.

Note that ROW_NUMBER cannot be used directly in a WHERE clause, so you have to wrap whole query in a subquery

Comment: what does the dash before the defId within the ```ROW FUNCTION``` mean?

Comment: It's a minus. It allows sorting the real defect ids: 1,2,3,4 ahead of 0 defect id, since -1 is less than 0